# why p value = 0 in CV-ANOVA?

Tags: cross-validation, data-visualization, multivariate-analysis

i am using SIMCA 13.0 to build a opls-da model. To validate the model,SIMCA perform ANalysis Of VAriance testing of Cross-Validated predictive residuals(CV-ANOVA).Then output a table(attached). In principle, the p-value <0.05 indicate model significance.
[image]

I have tried to display different number format like exponential, but the p-value is really a 0. So I think it not a problem of a limit of threshold to display.

So, if it make sense to report a 0 p value ? or just a problems of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the calculator at

https://www.socscistatistics.com/pvalues/fdistribution.aspx,

even when *F* is such that *F*(*k*-1,*n*-*k*) = *F*(160,484) = only 1.8, the *p*-value is < .00001.  Your *F* is 40.  The associated *p* is too small for your software to display without rounding down to 0, scientific notation or not.

You could verify this by making a copy of your data and doctoring it to reduce *F* to about 1.5.  You should see *p* rise to a printable level.

If you'd like people to comment on possible problems with your model, please say more about the model.